# Precise time for user input

Tags: c, time

Here's this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t t_ini,t_final;
    int n;
    float timer;
    t_ini=time(NULL);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    t_final=time(NULL);
    
    timer=difftime(t_final,t_ini);
    
    printf("%f",timer);
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to count the time for a user to input something so that if the time for the input exceeded the time limit i would print a "time limit exceeded" message. It works, but it counts only things like 9.000000 seconds or 5.000000 seconds, and i was looking for more precise decimals like 4.520000 seconds. Is there a simple way to do that using difftime?

Comment: Hint: [`clock_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock_t). `time_t` is an integer time value that only goes to the nearest second by definition.

Comment: @tadman C does _not_ specify `time_t`  "only goes to the nearest second by definition".  Perhaps that is your experience, though.  `clock_t` is a good idea.

Comment: `clock()` generally returns a considerably more precise value than `time()` but it measures a different thing (cpu time vs walltime.) For this particular question, I don't think either timer is appropriate. So you'll need to research the platform-specific timers on the platform(s) of interest.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Technically unspecified, but it has a long tradition of being `int`, hence the 2038 bug. As per the docs "this is almost always an integral value holding the number of seconds...since January 1, 1970 UTC". I'm curious if you know of a C compiler where that's not the case. While C doesn't seem to care, [POSIX does](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html).

Comment: @tadman `time_t` _is_ technically specified, as a _real type_ (integer or real floating type). "As per the docs" does not include the C spec - the one that matters most.  I've worked with various `time_t` that were `unsigned`, `double`, `long`, `int` and 64-bit integer scaled to nanoseconds and not all with a 1970 epoch UT (all compliant).  True that `time_t` is commonly  integer seconds from 1970 UT.  One finds more of these today in embedded which may lack an OS such as POSIX, than various OS's.